# 'SessionStore' object has no attribute 'cart' - Django

Tags: python, django

I generated a basket with 2 products, at the level of the basket page and also on this same page I added a form to insert the customer's name. by clicking on the submit button which will send the request to a view for insert into the database. but I have an error (**'SessionStore' object has no attribute 'cart'**)
I am using django-shopping-cart 0.1
and also I am using an API to post the products

Views.py

```
def postCommande(request):
  for key,value in request.session.cart.items:
    data={
    'products':[
             {
               'date':'23-09-22 00:00:00',
               'nameclient': request.POST['name'],
               'type':'typeproduct'
             }
          ]
       }
     url='http://myapi/products/postCommande'
     x=requests.post(url,json=data)

  return render(request,'panier/succes.html')
```

And the error is on this line (**for key,value in request.session.cart.items:**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session object is a `dict`-like object. Check Django documentation on [How to use sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/).

I think we should change

`for key,value in request.session.cart.items:`

to

`for key,value in request.session.get("cart", {}).items():`

To get your code to work.